# Compiling ANTLR 3C for AIX

Tags: c, gcc, antlr3, aix

I'm not too familiar with compiling for C, so if I don't give enough information, let me know what you need me to post!

Here's the summary: I need to run ANTLR in the target language of C on a somewhat old IBM AIX computer. I quickly gave up on compiling with the IBM CC/make utils and got a version of gcc (4.2) and GNU make on the machine. The issue is, while the configure script does detect the correct architecture, it does not seem to respond appropriately.

The specific version of ANTLR I am using is version 3.2, C target. The actual detected target is powerpc-ibm-aix-5.3.0.0

Here's what I've done. The first glaring error that I see is that it added the "-m32" flag to the options. Okay, I can remove that from the makefile simple enough, in which case gcc should default to -maix32.

Second issue: I get an error giving me the path to stdio.h and saying "error: duplicate 'unsigned'". Okay, so configure made a "define" statement in the auto-generated antlr3config.h file... I can comment that out, and the error goes away.

Third issue... this is where I'm stuck.

```
/opt/freeware/bin/make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/scrubber/libantlr3c-3.2'
if /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -Iinclude    -O2  -Wall -MT antlr3baserecognizer.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/antlr3baserecognizer.Tpo" -c -o antlr3baserecognizer.lo `test -f 'src/antlr3baserecognizer.c' || echo './'`src/antlr3baserecognizer.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/antlr3baserecognizer.Tpo" ".deps/antlr3baserecognizer.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/antlr3baserecognizer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -Iinclude -O2 -Wall -MT antlr3baserecognizer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/antlr3baserecognizer.Tpo -c src/antlr3baserecognizer.c -o antlr3baserecognizer.o
In file included from include/antlr3baserecognizer.h:39,
             from src/antlr3baserecognizer.c:9:
include/antlr3defs.h:343: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ANTLR3_SALENT'
make[1]: *** [antlr3baserecognizer.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/scrubber/libantlr3c-3.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is a link to the specific antlr3defs.c file included in the ANTLR library: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9XS1f8YfyB4cFJRZTdWM1pMWWs/edit?usp=sharing

Oh and I'm able to compile it on other platforms, like Ubuntu or Cygwin (I cannot use them for this task though). I'm not really familiar with AIX though and have limited experience with compiling C programs. Perhaps I need to set some things with the configure script?

Thanks!

EDIT: Made progress, so updating this post to keep the info together.

I was able to resolve the above error by adding the --disable-abiflags option when running the configure script... this option removes the -m32 and -m64 gcc flags. It allowed the configure script to work correctly, but left the assembler a little confused when running make. To give it guidance, I added the -Wa,-a32 flag to CFLAFS in the Makefile, thus letting the assembler know I wanted 32 bit.

There was just one issue remaining.

```
ar cru .libs/libantlr3c.a  antlr3baserecognizer.o antlr3basetree.o antlr3basetreeadaptor.o antlr3bitset.o antlr3collections.o antlr3commontoken.o antlr3commontree.o antlr3commontreeadaptor.o antlr3commontreenodestream.o antlr3convertutf.o antlr3cyclicdfa.o antlr3debughandlers.o antlr3encodings.o antlr3exception.o antlr3filestream.o antlr3inputstream.o antlr3intstream.o antlr3lexer.o antlr3parser.o antlr3rewritestreams.o antlr3string.o antlr3stringstream.o antlr3tokenstream.o antlr3treeparser.o antlr3ucs2inputstream.o
ar: 0707-128 The OBJECT_MODE environment variable has an invalid setting.
    OBJECT_MODE must be 32, 64, 32_64, d64 or any.
make[1]: *** [libantlr3c.la] Error 1
```

The problem is, it doesn't matter what I set it to. I have tried running make with it not set, and then used export to set it:

```
export OBJECT_MODE=32
```

I can type echo $OBJECT_MODE and it will indeed print out 32... but it seems to not detect it when I run make.

I was able to work around this by editing the "libtool" script to add "-X 32" to the ar options to override whatever it was reading. The long-term solution would probably be to ltmain.sh and re-run configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the line in question:

```
typedef socklen_t ANTLR3_SALENT;
```

because `socklen_t` is not defined you can't `typedef` it, including `socket.h` should fix it

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Edit:
After taking a second look at the file, `socket.h` should be included if you run the configure script

```
#ifdef HAVE_SOCKET_H
# include   <socket.h>
#else
# if HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
#  include  <sys/socket.h>
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: That got me thinking. Sure enough a lot of it is indeed failing. It just says "no" when you run the script for different tests, but the log makes it much clearer. It turns out the configure script runs gcc a lot... the problem is it includes the -m32 flag which apparently does not exist on gcc for AIX machines :( Do I need to generate my own configure script? I have never used autoconf. I COULD search/replace the -m32, but that seems hackish.

Comment: @shaddow try re-generating the configure script, run autoconf

Comment: I was able to use a configure option to work around it (I updated the original question). It would have been difficult to reconfigure the script since autoconf isn't installed on the machine I'm working with. I'm able to compile now though. Thank you!!